# OpenOCD error: gdb requested a non-existing register

Tags: c++, отладка, qtcreator, gdb, stm32

Добрый день!
  Прошу помочь разобраться с проблемой. Пытаюсь настроить отладчик (gdb 8.0) в QtCreator 4.2.1 для работы через плагин Bare Metal (OpenOCD 0.10.0). После запуска отладчик падает со следующей ошибкой "error: gdb requested a non-existing register".

Лог OpenOCD:

```
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0xf1000000 pc: 0x08000bc4 msp: 0x20005000
Error: gdb requested a non-existing register
Info : dropped 'gdb' connection
```

Команды инициализации OpenOCD в Bare Metal:

```
set remote hardware-breakpoint limit 4
set remote hardware-watchpoint-limit 2
monitor reset halt
load
monitor reset halt
```

Железо: STM32 Nucleo L073RZ,прошивка Nucleo_blink_led с сайта mbed.com, конфиг для OpenOCD взят с [http://openocd.zylin.com](http://openocd.zylin.com/#/c/3957/7/tcl/board/st_nucleo_l073rz.cfg)

OpenOCD запускается нормально, gdb через эмулятор терминала подключается, прошивка загружается, вроде бы все работает. Но хотелось бы работать через QtCreator.

UPD: Добавляю скрины настроек QtCreator (В русском Qt BareMetal - это устройства)

[image: Bare Metal OpenOCD]

UPD: Подтверждаю багу QTCreator'a. Я перешел на eclipse, поставил плагин для OpenOCD и теперь все прекрасно работает. Инструкцию по настройке брал с openstm32.org

Comment: А в плагине Bare Metal как-то выбирается контроллер? Похоже, что именно он запрашивает несуществующий регистр.

Comment: да, с этим вроде бы все нормально

Comment: Smetanin, с чем нормально? Я вижу, что с OpenOCD всё нормально, а с тем, кто к нему обращается - не нормально. Как вы выбрали контроллер? Есть какой-то конфиг в Bare Metal?

Comment: `watchoint` - здесь точно всё правильно?

Comment: в посте опечатка, поправил, вот полный скрин http://i.imgur.com/gWECpS0.png

Comment: Smetanin, судя по [этому документу](http://www.st.com/resource/en/data_brief/nucleo-f030r8.pdf), на вашей плате могут быть разные контроллеры. Какой именно у вас? Он точно соответствует тому, который указан в конфиге openocd? И я удивлён, что контроллер никак не задаётся в BareMetal. Возможно, вы не нашли конфиг.

Comment: у меня STM32L073RZT6, в конфиге openocd написано # This is an ST NUCLEO-L073RZ board with single STM32L073RZ chip. Могу выложить весь конфиг, если это поможет?

Comment: Гугель сообщает нам, что с версии 0.8.0 OpenOCD не поддерживает команду 'set tdesc'. https://sourceforge.net/p/openocd/mailman/message/32241205/ https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/tiva_arm/f/908/t/353029 Проверьте эту идею.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

похоже на багу QtCreator'а.

то же самое наблюдается в QtCreator 4.3 с stm32f103, после отката на 4.2 - бага пропала, но брейкпоинты не работают.

в QtCreator 3.6 - все работало почти прекрасно, но обновил системный Qt - и 3.6 начал падать при входе в настройки, пришлось экспериментировать с версиями...

на досуге еще поиграюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Ребят, это GDB глючит.
У меня с QtCreator 3.6 та же ошибка была. Родной

```
gdb --version
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
```

Тот который arm-none-eabi-gdb не имеет поддержку pithon, поэтому он не подходит. Возможно, можно его собрать с поддержкой python.

Когда подставил этот

```
arm-cortexa8-linux-gnueabihf-gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.7
```

Заработало.
работает